# What is an idiomatic and polite way to tell students to make their homwork handwritting clear and readable?

Tags: sentence-choice

I wonder how to politely tell students to make the *handwritting* of their homework clear and readable. I don't know the standard ways of saying this since I never see university professors emphasize the importance of nice handwrittings.

Comment: How about "Your homework must be typed" ... ?

Answer (score 3):

> Your homework should be easily legible.

> Make sure your homework is legible.

Legible, as defined by Google/Lexico

> (of handwriting or print) clear enough to read.
> *"the original typescript is scarcely legible"*